# Uninstalling a package from Ubuntu (sendmail-base) issue

Tags: ubuntu, sendmail, uninstall

I am trying to uninstall sendmail-base package but failed. Is there any way to remove this?

```
root@server:~# apt-get remove --purge sendmail-base 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  sendmail-base*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 1,274kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 67543 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing sendmail-base ...
Can't locate DebianNet.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.10 /usr/share/perl/5.10 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/sbin/update-inetd line 23.
dpkg: error processing sendmail-base (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 sendmail-base
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)



root@server# uname -a
Linux server 2.6.32-27-generic-pae #49-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 2 00:07:52 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux



root@server# dpkg -l sendmail-base
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Cfg-files/Unpacked/Failed-cfg/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                      Version                                   Description
+++-=========================================-=========================================-==================================================================================================
pF  sendmail-base                             8.14.3-9.1ubuntu1                         powerful, efficient, and scalable Mail Transport Agent
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you find `DebianNet.pm` on your system?

Use `apt-file search` to find the package that provides that file, install that package and retry removing.

Comment: Yes i  can.  

`apt-file search DebianNet.pm 
update-inetd: /usr/share/perl5/DebianNet.pm`

Comment: You probably want to install that package then, and retry the removal.

Comment: Thanks ! I found I did the following : apt-get install update-inetd && apt-get remove sendmail-base. Works great now!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why that isn't working.Try using this command line:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove sendmail-base
```

This will autoremove the dependencies, then you can try to remove it again.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem since upgrade to ubuntu 18.10.

I had to combine above answers to fix the problem.

```
sudo apt autoremove sendmail-base && sudo apt install update-inetd && sudo apt remove sendmail-base
```

Answer (score 0):

This package seems to require `Netbase` (which includes DebianNet.pm) to run its uninstall script. You can install this, and the pre-removal script should run correctly.

Comment: Package is on the system.

Comment: Package is on the system.

dpkg -l netbase
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold